# HAProxy - Forwarding Client Certificate to backend HashiCorp Vault servers

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, haproxy, hashicorp-vault, vaultsharp

I've been trying for about a week to setup a HashiCorp Vault environment, but have gotten stuck at setting up the last part: HAProxy, as I am unable to forward my Client Certificate to my backend.

My current setup on the HAProxy is this:

```
frontend vaultfrontend
        mode http
        bind *:8200 ssl crt /home/administrator/tls.crt verify none
        redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
        default_backend vaultbackend
backend vaultbackend
        mode http
        timeout check 5s

        option httpchk
        http-check connect ssl
        http-check send meth GET uri /v1/sys/health
        http-check expect status 200

        server a.vault a.vault.test.local:8200 ssl verify none check
        server b.vault b.vault.test.local:8200 ssl verify none check
        server c.vault c.vault.test.local:8200 ssl verify none check
```

My backend vault servers are running SSL with Windows CA signed certificates, and works just fine through their respective URLS.
The HAProxy has a signed certificate allowing people to connect to it via this URL: `https://vault.test.local:8200`, which works as expected.

The issue arises when I try to access the Vaults via HashiCorp Vault's Cert Auth authentication method.
Whenever I try to authenticate via `https://vault.test.local:8200` which is the HAProxy, I get an error message saying there's a lack of Client Certificate in the request:
`({"errors":["client certificate must be supplied"]})'`

It however works perfectly fine if I directly target my Vault servers instead.

I've tried to edit the config to include this: `http-request set-header X-Client-Cert %{+Q}[ssl_c_der,base64]` with different variations, but it changes nothing.
It really seems to me like HAProxy for whatever reason will not take my X-Client-Certificate being sent from my VaultSharp application (C#) and forward it.

Does anyone have a setup like this that works, or at least have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: It looks like this is an issue between HAProxy and Vault, so you may want to try this question in the Vault GitHub Issues? Let me know if there is any VaultSharp specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it solved, the issue is that performing SSL-Termination with HAProxy will always cause a Client Certificate to get lost (at least from all the things I ended up trying..)

The solution is to do SSL-Passthrough instead, and the Client Certificate will be read by the Vault environment correctly.

It would look something like this:

```
frontend vaultfrontend
        mode tcp
        bind *:8200
        redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
        default_backend vaultbackend
backend vaultbackend
        mode tcp
        timeout check 5s

        option httpchk
        http-check connect ssl
        http-check send meth GET uri /v1/sys/health
        http-check expect status 200

        server a.vault a.vault.test.local:8200 ssl verify none check
        server b.vault b.vault.test.local:8200 ssl verify none check
        server c.vault c.vault.test.local:8200 ssl verify none check
```

Comment: I think the mode in the frontend should be `http` for the redirect scheme to work